# Accessing an array by index won't warn about possibility of undefined?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to make sure, that the compiler will cry every time I try to access an array by index?

In my example, I explicitly say, that the record could be undefined, but the compiler still won't cry.

```js
type MyDataType =  { id: number, name: string };

const array: MyDataType[] = [
    { id: 1, name: "Hey folks" },
]

const record: MyDataType | undefined = array[1];
```

What is the best approach to make it evident, that `array[index]` can return `undefined` or maybe even `null`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Typescript 4.1 or later

Add [noUncheckedIndexedAccess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) to your `compilerOptions` in your tsconfig.json file.

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAiBDYiAq5oF4pQN5QEsATALigDsBXAWwCMIAnAGgsWojIGdgGDyBzKAF8A3ACgxAYwD25blEQMGiEGThIU6SAG0AulGzaxOHPmJkAjC3JsOUAEQAJCCCgAzaQBsA1p3vCmMV0JGTlgKAYIGQYiAwUlFW0AVl0RIA)

Comment: Note for others. Just FYI, in order to be able to use this flag, you must have Typescript version `4.1` or later mine was `3.9.7`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
type MyDataType =  { id: number, name: string };

type NullableArray<T> = {
    [K in number]: T | undefined
}

const array: NullableArray<MyDataType> = [
    { id: 1, name: "Hey folks" },
]

const record: MyDataType  = array[1];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=38&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAiBDYiAq5oF4pQN5QEsATALigDsBXAWwCMIAnAGgsWojIGdgGDyBzKAF8A3AFgAUJNCQoAOUoAbRYlqKIAQQYNEIADyoAfFGy5JOHAG0A0oXIUa9BgF0yqKAB8olckQgAzPggiSSFJSQBjAHtybihEbV0yBWVVdS0dfTgkFHRIY2xLcwt8YjIARhZyNg4oACIACQgQKH8oxQBrTjrhJklncIlo2OAoBghohlJYBGQ0DBxsBMzLcucRIA)